# Oat powder is moist after blending for two minutes. Safe to store?

Tags: food-safety, storage-method, blender, oats

I filled my blender about half way with instant oats and blended on high for about 2 minutes. When I took the lid off, I noticed moisture all inside the lid and and the oat powder is a little moist as well. Is it safe to store the oat powder in the original cardboard carton it came in? Should I try to get the moisture out of the powder first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must have been some moisture in your blender.  You could bake it off the oats, or you could freeze the wet powder, or just make whatever you were going to make.  But I think moist oat powder will go moldy within a few days.

Comment: My roommate said there's a possibility that the moisture could have come from the oats themselves, since they do have some water content.

Comment: No, instant oats are totally dry, like all stored grain products.  Otherwise they would get moldy in the cardboard can.

Comment: Turns out that's not true - there is an acceptable threshold for water content in grain storage http://www.knowledgebank.irri.org/step-by-step-production/postharvest/milling/milling-and-quality/measuring-moisture-content-in-milling#in-storage

Comment: If they ere sticky or tacky, it could have been the natural oils in oats (oats have a very high oil content which is why they can't easily be made into powders in the way that wheat can)